# I am looking for a book that teaches parents in Japan about the business side of kidnapping their own children

Tags: identification-request, japanese-language

I am looking for a book that teaches parents in Japan about the business side of kidnapping their own children.

I was alerted to the existence of this book by one Mr. Paul Evans, whose daughters were taken away by his monstrously abusive ex-wife. If you are interested in more details about that, you can read about it [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-living-in-Japan/answer/Paul-Evans-1091?comment_id=394178395&comment_type=2).

According to him, "There is a book on Amazon Japan that teaches parents in Japan about the business side of kidnapping your own children. This book is not banned. This book is not censored. It’s a cultural educational tool. I am NOT kidding."

Since I am a curious type, I am trying to track it down. I think that it is the following book.

[image: The Dark Side of the Biological Child Abduction Business]

- Japanese title: 実子誘拐ビジネスの闇
- Romanization: Jisshi Yuukai Bijinesu no Yami
- Literal translation: "The Dark Side of the Biological Child Abduction Business"

The writer of this book is one Ms. IKEDA Yoshiko (Japanese: 池田良子). It seems that she is a journalist who questions the absurdity and injustice in the world from a humanistic perspective.

[Here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/%E6%B1%A0%E7%94%B0-%E8%89%AF%E5%AD%90/dp/4864108277/ref=pd_lpo_sccl_2/356-5641488-3215349?pd_rd_w=OzvC1&content-id=amzn1.sym.c9d355d3-7242-4c45-8731-d024dd5a0fb6&pf_rd_p=c9d355d3-7242-4c45-8731-d024dd5a0fb6&pf_rd_r=HHXHD98531W80HCDAGG2&pd_rd_wg=uzbLi&pd_rd_r=2f900dc3-8e02-440d-af06-d485df499284&pd_rd_i=4864108277&psc=1) is the link to the book.

Is this the book that I am looking for? Or is it a different book?

Comment: Erm...are you asking us to confirm whether the book by Yoshiko is about kidnapping one's own children? That's kind of an unconventional ID-request, falls on the border of what is literature and what is not, and probably deducible based on reading the reviews and descriptions on the Amazon page.

Comment: There's simply not enough information to determine whether *this* is the book your source was talking about. It's just too vague of a description. Instead of coming here, why not ask Paul Evans directly?